# Ошибка при отправке письма при помощи php

Tags: email, php

Нужно для нескольких пользователей отправить письмо, содержание письма это результат выполнения php скрипта (для каждой записи скрипт разный, но иногда скрипты повторяются).

```
foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    ob_start();
    include($user['file']);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    mail($user['email'], $user['email_subject'], $message, $header);
}
```

Идет отправка письма с контентом $content. Все работает хорошо если нужно отправить 3 письма со скриптами A, B, C, но если нужно отправить 3 письма со скриптами A, B, B то первые два письма он отправляет когда очередть доходит до второго B то выдает ошибку

```
"PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 233832 bytes) in ..."
```

Подскажите как решить проблему

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); - я думаю это не нужно Вашему скрипту вообще.   
попробуйте установить в 0
```

Comment: include  также лучше поменять на include_once

Comment: ob_start() и    ob_end_clean() - тоже не понятно зачем для Вашей задачи